# Fix Outlook 2013 paragraph spacing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I've seen several questions for this problem but the solutions offered are not working for me.

I have installed Outlook 2013 for use with my outlook.com email address.

I want to be able to hit the enter key without concern, press it once and the spacing is just one line.  Press it twice, get two lines (thus some spacing between paragraphs.

What I am seeing is that when I hit the enter key, I get two lines when I read the email on Outlook.com

I have tried to edit the "Normal" style as well as use a custom style, but no matter what I do my emails have multiple line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the mail client (not web). There are two ways to work around this problem:

1) Manual: Use Ctrl + Shift + * to see the line breaks that Outlook is inserting. There are two kinds:

• Hard Returns Symbol - will space it by two
• Soft Returns - will space it by one (which is what you want)

By default, the mail client uses the hard return when you hit "Enter". It's annoying, so you need to backspace or delete that line, and then use "Shift + Enter" to use a soft return instead.

By using Ctrl + Shift + *, you're able to see the type of returns that are being used in your message and can fix it up accordingly.

If this is too much work, try **Option 2** below:

2) Install Auto Hot Key

Use this script below:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SendMode, Input
Return
#IfWinActive, - Message
$+Enter::Send, {Enter}
$Enter::Send, +{Enter}
```

If the script is actively running, hitting Enter will result in a soft return.

To learn how to set up this script, refer to http://www.autohotkey.com/